# Wordpress : Excluding last post from loop breaks navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to do something very simple here : I am trying to exclude last post from a loop in my theme's index.php file.

Everything is working fine except when I click on any links in the page, the browser only shows the homepage.

Here's the code for my loop :

```
<?php query_posts('offset=1'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title() ?>
        </a>
    </h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you I just did that but the links are still not working.

Comment: Here is the full code of my index.php file:
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
    <?php query_posts('offset=1'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title() ?>
            </a>
        </h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: This is the URL of my site in development : http://legrillepain.ca/

Comment: OK, two things: First: Your markup is broken.  Do a "view source", and you'll see this: `<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US"      <head>` - fix the `<html>` tag to be: `<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US" ><head>` .  Second, when you click the link, you **are** taken to a single post.  I suspect the problem is with your single post template - what does your `single.php` template look like?

Comment: I don't have any single.php file! That might explain the problem! I'll try to fix that, thanks again!

Comment: cale_b, you are the man! Thanks a lot!